# Rust: Unexpected behavior when returning a reference to a string

Tags: rust, reference

I am trying to create a function that finds the second word in a string to learn more about slice type.

```
fn find_second_word(s: &String) -> &str
{
    let mut first_space = true; // True if we havn't found first space yet
    let mut word_start_ind = 0; // The index of the first space
    for (i, &char_byte) in s.as_bytes().iter().enumerate()
    {
        if char_byte == b' '
        {
            if first_space
            {
                first_space = false;
                word_start_ind = i;
            }
            else
            {
                return &s[word_start_ind..i];
            }
        }
    }
    if first_space  // If there is no space at all in the string, then return an empty string
    {
        println!("No second word");
        return &"";  // Dangling Reference???
    }
    else
    {
        return &s[word_start_ind..s.len()]
    }
}
```

Which compiles and runs, but shouldn't `return &""` result in an dangling reference and thus preventing me from compiling and running the code?

Comment: `&""` is `&'static str` so live as long as the program live so you can always return it. Note that even if the code go to this branch the &String parameter will be borrow anyway.

Comment: @Stargateur but when I tried
`pub fn ref_test() -> &str{return &"";}`
the compiler didn't compile due to E0106, shouldn't that also work?

Comment: @sqz no, because in that case the compiler doesn't know what the lifetime of the returned string is. In the original, because there's an unnamed lifetime in a parameter it applies *lifetime elision* rules and assumes the lifetime of the return value matches. In the second, lifetime expansion can't trigger because that's not how it works, so despite there being only one likely (or even possible?) lifetime you have to name it explicitly.